# How to invoke LLVM code from a c++ program and pass data to it

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I have a c++ program which can generate LLVM IR at runtime. Now I want to compile this IR into a binary from my c++ program and invoke the binary. Also before invoking I want to pass data from my c++ program to the generated binary. I am new to LLVM and I couldnt find any documentation regarding this. Could someone point to a documentation about this or let me know how this can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the general block and tackle steps that come to mind even though you didn't state how you want to invoke the emitted code so I will assume it is as though you are invoking another executable:

**In your executable**

1. Generate the LLVM IR (see below)
2. Invoke, using a function like `system`, clang that will generate the new executable program from the LLVM IR.
3. If the compile is successful, then, using a function like `system`, call the newly generated executable and pass the data as command line arguments.

**LLVM IR Generated**

1. In the IR you are generating, you would need to emit a `main` function definition that takes `argc and argv` as that will be what consumes the passed data that you are sending.
2. In the `main` body you would need to handle the command line input appropriately and call the code you originally wanted exercised.

However: there are variations of this. For example, if you wanted to generate a dynamic library you could omit the generation of the `main` function and instead do a run-time load of the dynamic library you just created and resolve the function entry point.